# Map drive issue

Tags: networking, qnap

I need suggestion on sharing user files which is in QNAP-TS469U. Firmware 4.2 . I can ping this device both by name and ip. Also I can see AD users listed on QNAP when logged in to its interface. I simply cannot make any shared drive mappable. Some corruption has happened within the QNAP. Luckily I have asked all users to download their files and start working on it. But later when QNAP comes back on they will have to re update it. I know its a pain, but what could be the better way to share and sync at the same time when mapping a drive does not work?

To give more info:

I was able to map until 2 days back; we had no issues for like 5 months the day it got installed;
No PC in our network can map a drive since 2 days,nothing changed, it says, "windows cannot find the path" and when I run the diagnosis on windows, it says "remote device is not accepting connections".
I can log in to interface and looks everything healthy..

I did upgrade the firmware to 4.2 from 4.1, SMB is 3.0, I am new to this box, hence cannot troubleshoot enough.

Can anyone suggest me how users can share files now? The customer service of QNAP is so poor in Europe. They only have email support which may or may not give you reply, no phone support nothing.. their chat support, which always says you are in queue 2...and then 1 then says sorry we cannot connect you ,try again later.. such a poor service..

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like smbd or nmbd have stopped running on the QNAP. Log into the QNAP with ssh and see if they are running. If they are not running then try starting them manually.

To see if the services are running you can run `ps aux | grep mbd`.

Comment: Thanks... actually I resolved it by disabling microsoft file sharing service an d then re-enabling it. But still Cant figure out why this happened.